# Fixing "no rules expected the token" macro error

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to write a macro for destructuring BSON data which looks like this:

```
let bson: Document = ...;
let (id, hash, name, path, modification_time, size, metadata, commit_data) = bson_destructure! {
    get id = from (bson), optional, name ("_id"), as ObjectId;
    get hash = from (bson), as String, through (|s| ContentHash::from_str(&s));
    get name = from (bson), as String;
    get path = from (bson), as Bson, through (PathBuf::from_bson);
    get modification_time = from (bson), as UtcDatetime, through (FileTime);
    get size = from (bson), as I64, through (|n| n as u64);
    get metadata = from (bson), as Document, through (Metadata::from_bson);
    get commit_data = from (bson), optional, as Document, through (CommitData::from_bson);
    ret (id, hash, name, path, modification_time, size, metadata, commit_data)
};
```

I've written the following macro (pretty large) for it:

```
macro_rules! bson_destructure {
    // required field
    (
        @collect req,
        [$target:ident, $source:expr, $field:expr, Bson, $f:expr],
        [];
        $($rest:tt)*
    ) => {{
        let $target = try!(match $source.remove($field) {
            Some(v) => $f(v),
            None => Err(BsonDestructureError::MissingField {
                field_name: $field,
                expected: "Bson"
            }),
        });
        bson_destructure!($($rest)*)
    }};
    (
        @collect req,
        [$target:ident, $source:expr, $field:expr, $variant:ident, $f:expr],
        [];
        $($rest:tt)*
    ) => {{
        let $target = try!(match $source.remove($field) {
            Some(v) => match v {
                ::ejdb::bson::Bson::$variant(v) => $f(v),
                v => Err(BsonDestructureError::InvalidType {
                    field_name: $field,
                    expected: stringify!($variant),
                    actual: v
                })
            },
            None => Err(BsonDestructureError::MissingField {
                field_name: $field,
                expected: stringify!($variant)
            }),
        });
        bson_destructure!($($rest)*)
    }};

    // optional field
    (
        @collect opt,
        [$target:ident, $source:expr, $field:expr, Bson, $f:expr],
        [];
        $($rest:tt)*
    ) => {{
        let $target = try!(match $source.remove($field) {
            Some(v) => $f(v).map(Some),
            None => Ok(None),
        });
        bson_destructure!($($rest)*)
    }};
    (
        @collect opt,
        [$target:ident, $source:expr, $field:expr, $variant:ident, $f:expr],
        [];
        $($rest:tt)*
    ) => {{
        let $target = try!(match $source.remove($field) {
            Some(v) => match v {
                ::ejdb::bson::Bson::$variant(v) => $f(v).map(Some),
                v => Err(BsonDestructureError::InvalidType {
                    field_name: $field,
                    expected: stringify!($variant),
                    actual: v
                })
            },
            None => Ok(None),
        });
        bson_destructure!($($rest)*)
    }};

    // change variant name
    (
        @collect $k:tt,
        [$target:ident, $source:expr, $field:expr, $variant:ident, $f:expr],
        [as $nv:ident, $($word:ident $arg:tt),*];
        $($rest:tt)*
    ) => {
        bson_destructure!(
            @collect $k,
            [$target, $source, $field, $nv, $f],
            [$($word $arg),*];
            $($rest)*
        )
    };

    // change final mapping function
    (
        @collect $k:tt,
        [$target:ident, $source:expr, $field:expr, $variant:ident, $f:expr],
        [through ($nf:expr), $($word:ident $arg:tt),*];
        $($rest:tt)*
    ) => {
        bson_destructure!(
            @collect $k,
            [$target, $source, $field, $variant, $nf],
            [$($word $arg),*];
            $($rest)*
        )
    };

    // change field name
    (
        @collect $k:tt,
        [$target:ident, $source:expr, $field:expr, $variant:ident, $f:expr],
        [name ($nn:expr), $($word:ident $arg:tt),*];
        $($rest:tt)*
    ) => {
        bson_destructure!(
            @collect $k,
            [$target, $source, $nn, $variant, $f],
            [$($word $arg),*];
            $($rest)*
        )
    };

    // main forms
    (get $target:ident = from ($source:expr), $($word:ident $arg:tt),*; $($rest:tt)*) => {
        bson_destructure!(
            @collect req,
            [$target, $source, stringify!($target), Bson, Ok],
            [$($word $arg),*];
            $($rest)*
        )
    };
    (get $target:ident = from ($source:expr), optional, $($word:ident $arg:tt),*; $($rest:tt)*) => {
        bson_destructure!(
            @collect opt,
            [$target, $source, stringify!($target), Bson, Ok],
            [$($word $arg),*];
            $($rest)*
        )
    };

    // final form
    (ret $e:expr) => { $e }
}
```

However, the first example above results in the following compilation error:

```
src/db/data.rs:345:22: 345:25 error: no rules expected the token `opt`
src/db/data.rs:345             @collect opt,
                                        ^~~
```

I'm somewhat surprised that it doesn't show the error location as usual (that is, there is no indication where expansion happens), however, the error vanishes when I comment the piece of code which uses the macro out.

I can't see why it says that no rules expected this token because there is such a rule, but maybe I don't understand something.

I'm pretty sure that this is possible because that's roughly what quick_error crate does, but it seems that my macro writing skills are still lacking.

How should I fix the macro so it would work as I expect?

For completeness, the following is the definition of `BsonDestructureError`:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum BsonDestructureError {
    InvalidType {
        field_name: &'static str,
        expected: &'static str,
        actual: Bson
    },
    InvalidArrayItemType {
        index: usize,
        expected: &'static str,
        actual: Bson
    },
    MissingField {
        field_name: &'static str,
        expected: &'static str
    }
}
```

I'm also using `bson` crate reexported from `ejdb` crate. [Here](https://gist.github.com/netvl/11579e3b385ef2b52b6f) is a minimal example, runnable with [`cargo script`](https://github.com/DanielKeep/cargo-script) on stable Rust.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both `cargo script`, a recursive muncher, *and* my favourite internal rule syntax; how can I *not?*

First, the exact problem can be identified by running `cargo rustc -- -Z trace-macros`.  This will output each rule as it gets expanded, giving us a "backtrace" which, after some manual reformatting, comes out looking like so:

```rust
bson_destructure! {
    get id = from ( bson ) , optional , name ( "_id" ) , as ObjectId ;
    get hash = from ( bson ) , as String ;
    get name = from ( bson ) , as String ;
    get path = from ( bson ) , as Bson ;
    get modification_time = from ( bson ) , as UtcDatetime ;
    get size = from ( bson ) , as I64 , through ( | n | n as u64 ) ;
    get metadata = from ( bson ) , as Document ;
    get commit_data = from ( bson ) , optional , as Document ;
    ret ( id , hash , name , path , modification_time , size , metadata , commit_data )
}

bson_destructure! {
    @ collect opt ,
    [ id , bson , stringify ! ( id ) , Bson , Ok ] ,
    [ name ( "_id" ) , as ObjectId ] ;

    get hash = from ( bson ) , as String ;
    get name = from ( bson ) , as String ;
    get path = from ( bson ) , as Bson ;
    get modification_time = from ( bson ) , as UtcDatetime ;
    get size = from ( bson ) , as I64 , through ( | n | n as u64 ) ;
    get metadata = from ( bson ) , as Document ;
    get commit_data = from ( bson ) , optional , as Document ;
    ret ( id , hash , name , path , modification_time , size , metadata , commit_data )
}

bson_destructure! {
    @ collect opt ,
    [ id , bson , "_id" , Bson , Ok ] , [ as ObjectId ] ;

    get hash = from ( bson ) , as String ;
    get name = from ( bson ) , as String ;
    get path = from ( bson ) , as Bson ;
    get modification_time = from ( bson ) , as UtcDatetime ;
    get size = from ( bson ) , as I64 , through ( | n | n as u64 ) ;
    get metadata = from ( bson ) , as Document ;
    get commit_data = from ( bson ) , optional , as Document ;
    ret ( id , hash , name , path , modification_time , size , metadata , commit_data )
}
```

A careful perusal of the rules in `bson_destructure!` shows the issue: there is no rule which matches the third expansion.  `macro_rules!` is, frankly, *rubbish* at reporting sane error locations when it comes to recursive rules; that it's pointing to the `opt` token is irrelevant.  The *real* problem is that it couldn't find a matching rule.

In particular, the offending rule is this one:

```
// change variant name
(
    @collect $k:tt,
    [$target:ident, $source:expr, $field:expr, $variant:ident, $f:expr],
    [as $nv:ident, $($word:ident $arg:tt),*];
    $($rest:tt)*
) => {
    ...
};
```

Note the presence of a comma *immediately after* `$nv:ident`.  Also note that there *is no* such comma in the input.  This can be solved by moving the comma *inside* the repetition, like so:

```
// change field name
(
    @collect $k:tt,
    [$target:ident, $source:expr, $field:expr, $variant:ident, $f:expr],
    [name ($nn:expr) $(, $word:ident $arg:tt)*];
    $($rest:tt)*
) => {
    ...
};
```

Another alternative (and the one I ususally go with), is to simply mutate the input when it is first encountered to make sure there is *always* a trailing comma in place.

The code won't actually *compile* on my machine, due to a native dependency, but I did verify that making this change (both here, and to the other rules with a similar issue) allows it to complete macro expansion.  You can check the output looks correct using `cargo rustc -- -Z unstable-options --pretty=expanded`.

Comment: Wow, I wish I knew about `-Z trace-macros` before. I always think about such things as commas but now forgot them >_< Thank you very much!

Comment: using rustc version 1.31, I get an error using -Z.
Option 'Z' is only accepted on the nightly compiler

Comment: @John You need to use the nightly compiler, like the error message suggests.